# Is it possible to obtain an English certification online?

Tags: application, language, language-exams

> Assume that you are applying for a certain position and they require a proof that you master a given language at a [certain level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages).

Are there websites where you can fill out tests and obtain a certificate?

Comment: I'd tend to doubt it, because it would be nearly impossible to prove that you yourself took the test, rather than a stand-in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about academia.

Comment: @MadJack I understand. However, it is about a certification needed for an application procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You are able to demonstrate your proficiency in English by obtaining one of the certifications below. Mind you, these courses do take 120 + hours and extensive command of English (grammar) to complete. Choose properly accredited ones when possible that include a practical component. Bonus: A recognized TEFL, TESL or TESOL certification can net you a job as an English teacher aboard as it is internationally recognized.

**TEFL** – Teaching English as a Foreign Language

**TESL** – Teaching English as a Second Language

**TESOL** – Teaching English to Speakers of another Language

Comment: How do they verify that the person taking the tests is the one requesting the certification?

Comment: Accredited providers typically have some sort of practical component done through video/in class + an exam taken in person (requiring photo id). They would examine both for consistency.

Comment: I think the question was asking for pure on-line certification, no in-person exams.

Comment: Perhaps. It is possible to find fully online accredited course providers that require multiple photo ID submission at the beginning of the course. Then, during practical components done through webcam, they look to validate your identity.

Comment: Please see http://www.usnews.com/education/online-education/articles/2014/06/17/think-twice-before-cheating-in-online-courses for online proctoring techniques currently in place

Answer (score 0):

Well known Universities also provide such courses which are full-time, part-time and online. You can opt for online courses, and have yourself registered. These are recognized worldwide.
You can visit this site: http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/teaching-english/teaching-qualifications/celta/ways-to-take-celta/

Comment: To @Karlo From the link provided: _You only need to travel to your CELTA centre for lesson planning and teaching practice._